# Variable from controller in view

Tags: php, yii

I have a function in my controller which returns data from a different model. When I call the function in my view, I get the error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Submission::loadJournal()**. I get that it can't find the function, but what am I doing wrong?

## in SubmissionController.php

```
public function loadJournal($journal_id)
{
    $modelObject=Object::model()->findByPk($journal_id);
    if($modelObject===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $modelObject;
}
```

## in _form.php

```
<?php 
    $journal_id = $_POST['journal_id'];
    $journal=Submission::loadJournal($journal_id); 
    echo $journal; 
?>
```

Comment: Look in your Submission model (not controller or view) for a loadJournal method (function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<?php 
    $journal_id = $_POST['journal_id'];
    $journal= $this->loadJournal($journal_id); 
    echo $journal; 
?>
```